# populate viewmodel property on razor view from js function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

On razor Edit view I have besides others viewmodel properties CityId property. Those property should be populated from combobox selection.

MyViewModel

```
public int CityId {get; set;}
```

edit.cshtml

```
@model MyViewModel
<div id="CitiesDivId" class="editor-field">
     <select id="CitiesId" name="Cities"></select>
</div>
```

inside js function I'm able to grab cityId from combobox

```
var selectedCity = $('#CitiesId').val();
```

my question is:

how to populate `CityId` viewmodel property with this selectedCity variable value (from js). This way I will receive only viewmodel at `httppost` controller action (I do not want to send this selectedCity using ajax).

Comment: Why not use `@Html.DropDownListFor(...)`, tied to the `CityId` property?

Comment: This question is currently not answer-able.  We have no idea what your controller method signature is.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fill a model object from js values? I think that this is not possible